# Is "relaxed" synchronization of threads in block possible in CUDA?

Tags: cuda, synchronization

I know what `__syncthreads()` is and I would like to do a little bit different thing:

```
__global__ void kernel()
{
  __shared__ array[1024];
  some other declarations

  load some data into array
label1:
  do some other independent calculations

label2:
  use data from array
  ...
}
```

So I could do `__syncthreads()`; at label2. It has the semantics that threads can go beyond `label2` only if all threads have reached `label2`.

What I actually need is to ensure that threads can pass beyond `label2` when all other threads have reached `label1`. Such a barrier is weaker and I hope it would block my program less. Is there any kind of relaxed barrier like this possible?

Comment: What makes you sure that all the threads will pass `label1` when first reaches `label2`? How do you define 'first thread' ?

Comment: I roughly understand how GPU works, but of course can't be totally sure. GPU takes threads 0-31, executes one operation for them. If operation takes more than one cycle, GPU executes one operation for threads 32-63...  So the more additional calculations after memory read - the more probability that there will be enough cycles to insert execution of other threads.
Memory reads, if they are at the beginning of a kernel, will be started, I suppose, very close to each other and finish after many cycles but also together.

Comment: It may be possible with some use of `__shared__` memory atomics to construct a "conditional" `__syncthreads()` operation.  Without a full example or test case, it's not clear to me that it would likely yield much benefit over just issuing `__syncthreads()` normally.  [Insofar as `__syncthreads()` is currently exposed at the CUDA C/C++ level](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#synchronization-functions), there is no built-in  conditional capability along the lines of what you are asking for..

Comment: Using shared memory however itself requires the use of `__syncthreads()` for correct initialization. It might still provide a net benefit as threads will not have progressed much during initialization, or if initialisation cost can be amortized in multiple uses of the homebuild sync construct. But it has a lot of cost to amortize vs. the simple solution of running more than one block per SM to make `__syncthreads()` cheap.

Comment: PTX has a related mechanism for producer-consumer schemes via the [`bar.arrive`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#parallel-synchronization-and-communication-instructions-bar) instruction that is not exposed at the CUDA C level. But I can't immediately see how that can easily be made to work here, as consumers still have to wait for all other consumers.

Comment: I have been pondering for a while why PTX didn't completely separate the arrival and blocking aspects of `bar.sync` when `bar.arrive` was introduced, but presumable `bar.arrive` was a cheap add-on, while a blocking sync without arrival would have been more expensive because it prevents immediate reuse of the barrier (the number of blocking barriers to come in that model is unknown without keeping a second counter).

Answer (score -2):

You can safely omit `__syncthreads()` only when the size of a block is equal to the size of warp (or half). This technique is called "warp-synchronous programming". Because of the fact that all threads within one warp execute simultaneously you can be sure that they some point they already executed prior instructions. In other cases, you can only assume that all the threads within a block are past some part of kernel - and it's very very risky assumption.

Comment: Read the original (not edited) question before down-voting my answer. If you still disagree - use comment to tell me what's wrong with it.

Comment: I believe it was downvoted before I edited the question. The original version was asking the same thing as my edit, but in an indirect/convoluted way. As such this is not an answer to the problem. (not my downvote though)